# Pass Table to a stored Procedure give an error with Invalid column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure (usp_Roll_UP) which will be called from other procedures. I get the below error message. I copy that data to a #temp table and Query by one of the columns on the table. The reason i am using #Temp. I need to Delete the data as it is processed in the procedure.

I get the below error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_Roll_UP, Line 38 [Batch
>   Start Line 235] 
>   Invalid column name 'T_Week'.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Usr_defined_Table ] AS TABLE(
    [T_Year] [int] NULL,
    [T_Week] [int] NULL,
    [Measure] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Amount] [numeric](16, 2) NULL
)

Create Procedure usp_Roll_UP
   @AllData Usr_defined_Table READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM @AllData 
    SELECT * FROM @AllData  WHERE [T_Week] =5  -- Works give the records
    SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE [T_Week] =5  -- give me an error with 

--- More business logic here. as the records are processed, i need to delete ---the data from this #Temp
END
```

Comment: `[dbo].[Usr_defined_Table ]` vs (what is effectively) `[dbo].[Usr_defined_Table]` (notice the lack of space at the end of the second name)?

Comment: Otherwise, I can't replicate your error: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=433edb1f30b1b7dbb3b1d3c7426598e2)

Comment: What you posted doesn't seem to happen in the example as you posted it. But I have to ask why you pass in a table valued parameter and then immediately copy that data into a temp table. Seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: @Sean Lange One day I did the same when correcting long running sp that was already in production and should have the same interface(table valued parameter). The real volume passed to sp was some mlns of rows, it was the only mode to tell the server the real  data volume: copy to temp table, as table variable was estimates as 1 row...

Comment: @sepupic that makes sense. I guess I have heard that being an issue but I have never passed large volumes of data through table valued parameters. ;)

Comment: You could create and populate the #temp table in the calling proc and then access it in the child proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thies means that in your session where you try to save yor sp by executing `Create Procedure`
there is already temp table called `#Temp` and this table has no column called `T_Week`.

Just drop this table before you execute your `create proc`.

Your `create proc` cannot pass the parse because there is already temp table with the same name but another structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot keep the same name.

SELECT * INTO #AllData  FROM @AllData 
I changed from above line to below fixed the issue

SELECT * INTO #Temp  FROM @AllData